# How can delete Click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I completely delete the $(selector).click() event?

I created option buttons and I would like to stop the click event so that the user won't be able to change the option already selected.

How to complete the overriding of the click (or any other) event on jquery?

Comment: Did you even search your problem? Googling "remove jQuery events" it's all you have to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [jQuery unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/)

```
$('#foo').unbind('click');
```

This will unbind click event from element with id `foo`.
As @notzippy mentioned disabling button will be a better idea.

Answer (score 1):

Usual method is to disable the button, that gives a visual indication that the button cannot be clicked and will not fire click events.

Answer (score 0):

Do:

```
$(selector).unbind('click');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(selector).unbind()
```

will remove all handlers.

```
$(selector).unbind('click');
```

will remove the click handlers.

In jQuery 1.7+, you should apply handlers with `.on()` and remove them with `.off()`.